# How do I loop through subdirectories?

Tags: php, dynamic, foreach, directory, gallery

I asing php mainly in 000webhost.com. Very novice/beginner. I learned most of what I know from youtube and developphp.com .

Okay so my question. I am trying to build a dynamic gallery page without using flash. It has to be dynamic because i want a user to be able to upload a picture then have it show up on the gallery page. So far so good. I am looking for some sort of foreach (is_dir(/Albums/)) call to loop through my albums directory and look for all folders and then add them to the page. Right now i have to manually input everything. This is what it looks like.

```
<table width="100%"><tr><td width="78%"><span class="textbg">Miller Albums</span></td><td width="22%"><?php echo $toplinks; ?></td></tr></table><span class="textsm"></span><p class="desc"></p><p><span class="textreg">Click an album to see the pictures</span><br><a href="http://miller.netai.net/member_profile.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Home</a>
</p><hr size="1">
<table style="text-align: center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<a href="/Albums/CRFA"><img width="150" height="150" border="0" align="middle" title="CRFA" src="/Albums/CRFA/thumbnail.jpg"></a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="/Albums/Internet%20Pics"><img width="150" height="150" border="0" align="middle" title="Internet Pics" src="/Albums/Internet%20Pics/thumbnail.jpg"></a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="/Albums/Dads%20Wedding"><img width="150" height="150" border="0" align="middle" title="Dads Wedding" src="/Albums/Dads Wedding/thumbnail.jpg"></a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="/Albums/Dads%20Wedding%20(cont.)"><img width="150" height="150" border="0" align="middle" title="Dads Wedding (cont.)" src="/Albums/Dads Wedding (cont.)/thumbnail.jpg"></a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label><font size="3">Ben's Fire Academy</font></label>
</td>
<td>
<label><font size="3">Internet Pics</font></label>
</td>
<td>
<label><font size="3">Dad's Wedding</font></label>
</td>
<td>
<label><font size="3">Dad's Weding (cont.)</font></label>
</td>
</tr></tbody></table>
<map name="Map">
<area href="frameset.htm" coords="95,1,129,44" shape="rect">
</map>
</body>
```

I'd like to have something in the body like...

```
 <table style="text-align: center">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
<?php
foreach(is_dir(/Albums/))
    <td>
    <a href="/Albums/%dir%">
    <img width="150 height="150" border="0" align="middle" title="%dir%" src="/Albums/%dir%/thumbnail.jpg"></a>
    </td>

IF no_more_dir
    exit();
?>
        </tr>
```

Is there anyway to do this or am I in way over my head?

Comment: A font element? Haven't seen one of those in a long time...

Comment: glob() is a good place to start.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

Answer (score 8):

You could use [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) for this

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('/path/to/directory') as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDir() && !$fileInfo->isDot()) {
        // Do whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: RecursiveDirectoryIterator might be a better solution for sub-albums and whatnot.

Comment: Possibly, but it depends on the folder structure and the intentions of the `// Do whatever`

Comment: It is only going to be 1 folder deep. I have formatting once they get into the correct album I just don't have a dynamic folder display. You land at /Albums, show the folders, click a folder, land at /Albums/Tuesday, and see a list of all photos located at /Albums/Tuesday/images

Comment: You're encouraged to use the `FilesystemIterator` over the old and quirky `DirectoryIterator`. Skipping dots comes for free with the former.

Answer (score 5):

You're on the right track!

This does what you need it to do: 
http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

```
$album_dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('path/to/album_root');
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($album_dir) as $filename => $file) {
    // echo img tag
}
```

Answer (score 4):

While I'd love to advocate the iterators, another option would be to get an array of folders with.

```
glob('path/to/albums/*', GLOB_DIR)
```

---

If you do want to go the iterator route, then a [`ParentIterator`](http://php.net/parentiterator) would come in handy to easily only iterate over directories.

```
$dirs = new ParentIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('path/to/albums'););
$it  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dirs, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

// Optionally, limit the depth of recursion with $it->setMaxDepth($number)

foreach ($it as $dir) {
    // Output your HTML here
}
```

Comment: how to access $dir then?